# I need to count the total of subscribers in a given rank over time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following format:

| user_iD | user_rank | rank_updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2021-06-18 |
| 2 | A | 2021-06-18 |
| 3 | A | 2021-06-18 |
| 4 | A | 2021-06-18 |
| 2 | B | 2021-06-19 |
| 3 | B | 2021-06-19 |
| 1 | B | 2021-06-20 |
| 2 | C | 2021-06-20 |
| 4 | B | 2021-06-20 |
| 4 | C | 2021-06-21 |

I need it to be like:

| date | rank | rank_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-18 | A | 4 |
| 2021-06-18 | B | 0 |
| 2021-06-18 | C | 0 |
| 2021-06-19 | A | 2 |
| 2021-06-19 | B | 2 |
| 2021-06-19 | C | 0 |
| 2021-06-20 | A | 0 |
| 2021-06-20 | B | 3 |
| 2021-06-20 | C | 1 |
| 2021-06-21 | A | 0 |
| 2021-06-21 | B | 2 |
| 2021-06-21 | C | 2 |

and i need to count how many users with the given rank A,B or C exists until a date. Until now I've the following (where `my_table` is the data source):

```
With Users_rank AS (
    Select
        "user_id" AS "user_id",
        Cast("rank_updated" AS date) AS "rank_updated"
        rank() OVER(partition "user_id" OVER "rank_id") as "user_rank"
    FROM "my_table"
)

Select "rank_updated", "user_id", max("user_rank")
FROM Users_rank
GROUP BY "rank_updated", "user_id"
ORDER BY "rank_updated"
```

This give me the following result:

| rank_updated | user_id | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-18 | 1 | A |
| 2021-06-18 | 2 | A |
| 2021-06-18 | 3 | A |
| 2021-06-18 | 4 | A |
| 2021-06-19 | 2 | B |
| 2021-06-19 | 3 | B |
| 2021-06-20 | 1 | B |
| 2021-06-20 | 2 | C |
| 2021-06-20 | 4 | B |
| 2021-06-21 | 4 | C |

Now I need only to count how many has a given rank until the days, but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `cross join` to get all dates with all ranks.  Then bring in the existing data:

```
select gs.date, v.user_rank, count(t.user_rank) as on_day,
       sum(count(t.user_rank)) over (partition by v.user_rank order by gs.date) as running_cnt
from generate_series('2021-06-18'::date, '2021-06-21'::date, interval '1 day') gs(date) cross join
     (values ('A'), ('B'), ('C')) v(user_rank) left join
     t
     on t.user_rank = v.user_rank and
        t.date = gs.date
group by gs.date, v.user_rank;
```

Comment: There is only one problem, seems that the users who have "upgraded" the rank keeps counting on the old value. ;-;